# await WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync not working

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, webclient

I'm trying to use `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync` to download a file so that I can make use of the download progress event handlers. The problem is that even though I'm using await on `DownloadFileTaskAsync`, it's not actually waiting for the task to finish and exits instantly with a 0 byte file. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Download("http://ovh.net/files/1Gb.dat", "test.out");
    }

    private async static void Download(string url, string filePath)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            webClient.Proxy = webProxy;
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.Write($"{e.ProgressPercentage}%");
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine();
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not awaiting `Download` method in main. Try `Download("url", "path").Wait();`

Comment: You need to declare `Main` as `static async Task Main()` and inside it you need to `await Download(...)`

Comment: You're not waiting for the task to complete. If you want a quick (but generally bad) fix while testing things, add `.Wait()` after `Download()`, but if you're new to async-await I suggest you read up on how to do it correctly (the web is full of good references for it).

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed, The two methods shown are either not asynchronous or not awaitable.

First, you need to make your download method awaitable:

```
private async static Task DownloadAsync(string url, string filePath)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        IWebProxy webProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        webProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        webClient.Proxy = webProxy;
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => Console.Write($"{e.ProgressPercentage}%");
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine();
        await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), filePath).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Then, you either wait on `Main`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    DownloadAsync("http://ovh.net/files/1Gb.dat", "test.out").Wait();
}
```

Or, [make it asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main), too:

```
private static async Task Main()
{
    await DownloadAsync("http://ovh.net/files/1Gb.dat", "test.out");
}
```